# How to programmatically open and select a Suggested Action in the Quick Actions menu in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

While it is possible to programmatically make the Quick Actions (lightbulb) menu visible in Visual Studio (see below)...

[image: lightbulb menu]

...what I'd actually like to do is make the Quick Actions menu visible AND programmatically select a certain Suggested Action without the user having to click on the lightbulb to trigger it (essentially, the original lightbulb state looks like the image below rather than the one above). Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: It seems you want to change the behavior of light bulb? Normal way: light bulb appears=>click=>display quick actions and what you want: light bulb appears and display quick actions context automatically. There seems to no appropriate api to achieve this goal.

Comment: That's correct @LanceLi-MSFT , though I should clarify, I don't want _all_ lightbulb menus to behave this way, only the one that I'm trying to programmatically control.